# Qduino Mini bricked?

Tags: programming, hardware, keyboard, arduino-mini

So I have been experimenting with keyboard inputs and I think I may have accidentally put a loop in my code that never actually ends the keyboard input thus not allowing me to upload any sketches to fix the problem.

Here is the error code I got when I tried to upload a blank into the qduino:

```
Arduino: 1.8.1 (Windows Store 1.8.1.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Qduino Mini"

Build options changed, rebuilding all
Sketch uses 4136 bytes (14%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28672 bytes.
Global variables use 148 bytes (5%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2412 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2560 bytes.
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
processing.app.SerialException: Error opening serial port 'COM11'.
    at processing.app.Serial.<init>(Serial.java:125)
    at processing.app.Serial.<init>(Serial.java:66)
    at processing.app.SerialMonitor$3.<init>(SerialMonitor.java:93)
    at processing.app.SerialMonitor.open(SerialMonitor.java:93)
    at processing.app.AbstractMonitor.resume(AbstractMonitor.java:110)
    at processing.app.Editor.resumeOrCloseSerialMonitor(Editor.java:2240)
    at processing.app.Editor.access$2400(Editor.java:77)
    at processing.app.Editor$DefaultExportAppHandler.run(Editor.java:2315)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - COM11; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port busy.
    at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:164)
    at processing.app.Serial.<init>(Serial.java:114)
    ... 8 more
Error opening serial port 'COM11'.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok strange, just after posting this the qduino decided to flash a different light on me so I try to upload again and it works... So apperantly just by keeping the qduino connected for some time it will start to work again...